# I can't seem to get my local shared MySQL data volume to persist on Docker for Windows

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm using the latest Docker for Windows on Win 10 with following run command:

```
docker run -d -e APP=db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -v /C/Users/myuser/Documents/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql --name=db -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest
```

When I start the container and check the ~/Documents/mysql_data directory, there's nothing there.

The data persists reboot, but when I stop, remove and re-run the container, the data is gone.

I am on a security-restricted Windows 10 laptop with 16GB of RAM, where sharing files works fine for my PHP container with a similar run command.

I expected to have MySQL's ibData files in my local mysql_data directory and the ability to persist container re-run. Is this a bug, or am I getting the expected behavior or doing something wrong?

Edit: When I `docker exec -it bash db` into the database container, there's this output when I `df -h`

```
//10.0.75.1/C   236G  109G  127G  47% /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's either a Windows Firewall or Antivirus issue, but wanted to see if I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

you can show docker logs：docker logs db
try follow：
docker run -d -e APP=db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -v /C/Users/myuser/Documents/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql:rw --name=db -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest